# What are the impacts on churches and Christian practice (if any) because of Indonesia's updated criminal code?

Tags: civil-government, religious-freedom

[The Australian Associated Press reports](https://www.examiner.com.au/story/8005688/indonesia-to-penalise-sex-outside-marriage/):

> Decades in the making, the new criminal code is expected to be passed on December 15, Indonesia's deputy justice minister Edward Omar Sharif Hiariej told Reuters.

I'm interested to learn whether there are *new* impacts of this updated code on churches and Christians's freedom to practice their faith *beyond* the existing restrictions, even though compared to other Moslem majority countries Indonesia remains one that constitutionally and legally accords the most freedom for Christians, supported partly by a Christian minority political representation in various levels of government.

Yet the lobby of hardline Islamic parties may erode further this freedom through introducing various restrictions on various lower level code downstream from the constitution or at provincial/local levels, as they have done in the past:

> The draft has the support of some Islamic groups in a country where conservatism is on the rise, although opponents argue it reverses liberal reforms enacted after the 1998 fall of authoritarian leader Suharto.

In 2019, [The Associated Press reported](https://apnews.com/article/d45e02a684024700a0edccdcf72bf8f1) that the delayed vote of the draft, minimally changed since then, includes expansion of the Blasphemy law:

> It also expands a current Blasphemy Law and maintains a 5-year prison term for deviations from the central tenets of Indonesia’s six recognized religions — Islam, Protestantism, Catholicism, Hinduism, Buddhism and Confucianism.
>
> Rights activists say more than 150 people, most of them religious minorities, including former Jakarta Gov. Basuki Tjahaja Purnama, have been convicted under the 1965 Blasphemy Law.

While it appears that Christianity may also benefit, for example protection from sacrilege of sacred Christian symbols such as the cross, I worry that this expansion has the (un-)intended side effect of restricting inter-religious dialogues because of increasing risk that Christians can be accused of disrespecting other religions's sacred text when Christians discuss / mention Qur'an verses in a multi-faith context, for example.  (The Christian Gov. Basuki Tjahaja Purnama was convicted of insulting Qur'an verses, [a charge that he denied](https://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2016/10/07/ahok-denies-he-insulted-the-quran.html)).

My question is specifically about **what changed in the updated 2022 code that specifically impact Christian faith practice**, not the criminalization of broad-based *secular* freedom which is the main focus of the above 2022 news report.

Comment: I understand if users vote this to be off-topic to be posted in Law.SE but I prefer to post here due to the community's better knowledge of the specific faith practices that can be inhibited such as evangelism, religious education and publication, proselytizing, building of new churches, [providing of disaster relief](https://www.christianitytoday.com/news/2022/november/indonesia-earthquake-cianjur-christian-churches-jakomkris.html), activities of foreign missionaries, mixed-faith family laws, etc.